# Best practice for sharing common schema for JAX-WS based maven projects

Tags: maven, jax-ws

I'm looking for best way to structure maven projects which use JAX-WS, specifically where multiple JAX-WS projects which share common schema.

For example, if we have the following structure

```
ProjectA    
    |- pom.xml    
    \- src
         \- wsdl
              \- projectA.wsdl 
ProjectB    
    |- pom.xml    
    \- src
         \- wsdl
              \- projectB.wsdl
```

Both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` import `CommonTypes.xsd`. Where should we put CommonTypes.xsd and how should we configure ProjectA & ProjectB so jaxws-maven-plugin is able to process them correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to put the CommonTypes.xsd in an extra Maven project which is deployed to your maven repository. For simplicity I would create this as jar project and only inlcude the xsd file.

The your projectA and B can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) to unpack the xsd to a specific folder in ProjectA/B where your wsdl is expecting the xsd:

```
     <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>groupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>commont-types-xsd</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
               <type>jar</type>
               <overWrite>true</overWrite>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
             </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Maybe you need to play around with the execution order because the jaxws-plugin is also running in the generate-sources cycle or maybe change the dependency plugin to an earlier phase.

An other solution would be to create the extra project and having something like a catalogue service server were you store the xsd files common over all projects and the wsdl just needs to point to this server url.

Comment: I accept this answer as this is exactly what I'm doing at this moment.